# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'RCTWebSocketManager.connect\')

Tags: ios, react-native

I m using `React-native v0.10.0` and getting this screen:

[image]

Ok, So I figure out I m doing something wrong.

So I downloaded the code from this [official React-native website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html) for integrating `React-native` into existing app using `pod`.

The downloaded code uses `React-native v0.2.1` and everything looks good there.
So I copied the whole code and overrode mine, but the red screen still appears. It left me just with the changes of the `React-native`ץ

Is there any chance that the current version of `React-native v0.10.1` doesn't work at all? :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No great advice, but I basically stacked my files away and did a new react-native init after upgrading from 0.4.0 to 0.9.0 which fixed it...

Comment: I didn't use react-native with ```react-native init <project-name>``` I used it via ```cocoapod```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success by adding `pod 'React/RCTWebSocket'` to the `Podfile` as well and running `pod install` again.

Comment: Thanks, But U just added a deprecated code into your project :/
https://github.com/tptee/RCTWebSocket

Comment: I'm afraid the troubleshooting pages are out of date as well then; https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html#xcode-build-failures

Comment: I also had this issue and it was resolved by the solution proposed by @jrnk 
Added these to the pod file:
   pod 'React/RCTNetwork'
   pod 'React/RCTWebSocket'

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because `RCTWebSocketManager` is not defined in your bundled app. The `connect` method of an object cannot be called on an `undefined` or `null` object.

To resolve this problem in iOS open *Build Phases* for your app target and ensure `libRCTWebSocket.a` exists in the *Link Binary with Libraries* section. If the item is not listed and not available for addition then add `RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj` to your app's *Libraries* folder in Xcode and try linking again.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem rather trivial, but check to make sure that you have deleted react-native from the node_modules directory within the directory of react-native-router in the app's node_modules directory. If react-native is listed again the app will throw an error.

I have experienced this issue on a couple of occasions and this has been the cause for the error.