# React Native Podfile subspecs are not added to project

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm seeing the same error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32330988/2348392) with React-native 0.19.0 in an iOS app.

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'RCTWebSocketManager.connect\')
```

I have an existing project and followed the steps in the [Integrating with Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html) documentation. None of the answers from the existing question worked for me.

My Podfile is exactly like the example shown in the React Native documentation:

```
pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTWebSocket'   
]
```

After a `pod install`, the Pods in my Xcode project only contain the React Core library, not the libraries listed in the subspecs.

To convince myself that it wasn't a conflict with other dependencies listed in my Podfile, I created a brand new project, followed the steps in the documentation, and got the same results.

Any suggestions for what to try next are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting node_modules path. Right now it is './node_modules/react-native'. Try to change it to '../node_modules/react-native'

hope this helps

> ```
> pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', 
> :subspecs => [ 'Core', 'RCTText', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTWebSocket' ]
> ```